# Remove substring in jQuery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox, substring

I'm using the jQueryUI combobox.  If the user enters a string that isn't an `option` in the `select` element it creates a new `option` element with that value.  The problem is that it currently prepends 'undefined' the the value that was entered.  How could I remove the 'undefined' substring before it submits?  Here's the code:

```
change: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
            valid = false;
        select.children("option").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (!valid) {
            new_value = self.options.precede_new_with + $(this).val();
            option = $('<option value="' + new_value + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
            select.append(option);
            select.val(new_value);
            return false;
        }
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it appears the problem is that self.options.precede_new_with is returning 'undefined'.

Answer (score 2):

You mean this line ?

```
new_value = self.options.precede_new_with + $(this).val();
```

When creating the instance of the combobox, set this option to an empty string:

```
$( "#combobox" ).combobox({
    precede_new_with: ''
});
```

Or change the implementation to check for a possible undefined by returning an empty string in that case:

```
new_value = (self.options.precede_new_with || '' ) + $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

While appending the `option` you can check if it is undefined then prepend it with empty string. This way you don't have to do any processing while submitting the form.

Try this.

```
if ( !valid ) {

   new_value = (self.options.precede_new_with || '') + $(this).val();
           //this will prepend empty string if undefined

   option = $('<option value="' + new_value + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
   select.append(option);
   select.val(new_value);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: @Dowvoter - Can you please leave the reason, so that I can fix the issue and answer can become useable to others?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions, sorry it took me a bit to get back, I've been busy as all hell.  Anyway I ended up just needing to set `new_value` equal to `$(this).val()` and get rid of `self.options.precede_new_with`.